# Оператор * из Python в C++

Tags: python, c++, операторы

Как в C++ можно реализовать питоновский `*` оператор для раскрытия коллекции в нужное количество переменных?

Примеры:

```
std::vector x = {1, 2, 3};
const auto [a, b, c] = star(x);
const auto l = [](int x, int y, int z) {};
l(star(x));
```

Comment: в общем случае - никак. Но есть  va_arg, есть разворачивания пакета с помощью троеточия. Но обычно это все решается другими способами. Скорее всего, у Вашей задачи есть более красивое плюсовое решение.

Comment: Объявите x - `std::tuple<int,int,int>`, вместо vector, либо напищите функцию преобразования из произвольно типа в tuple. Проблема в том, что функция star должна знать количество переменных в коллекции в compile-time (чтобы знать тип возвращаемого tuple). Т.е. это может быть реализовано только с коллекциями фиксированного размера (std::array).

Comment: @Chorkov `error: cannot convert 'std::tuple<int, int, int>' to 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::tuple x ={ 1, 2, 3 }; // std::vector x = {1, 2, 3};
const auto [a, b, c] = x; //  = star(x);
const auto l = [](int x, int y, int z) {};
std::apply(l, x) ; //     l(star(x));
```

Или, используя std::array и стандартный массив вместо tuple (требуется C++20):

```
int x[] ={ 1, 2, 3 }; // std::vector x = {1, 2, 3};
const auto [a, b, c] = std::to_array(x);
const auto l = [](int , int , int ) {};
std::apply(l, std::to_array(x)) ; //     l(star(x));
```

Comment: Надо, чтобы `star` работал для любых iterable, как и в питоне

Comment: Для любых iteratabke может получиться, только если вы готовы вручную передавать список типов (или хотя бы его длину) при каждом вызове star, поскольку в динапических коллекциях невозможно определить длину в compile-time.

Comment: для iterable времени компиляции

Comment: @wine iterable , с фиксированной длинной, это только std::array и массивы из C. Зачем это может понадобиться?